# wpf in c# returning error "not all code paths return a value" on GetProductRecords()

Tags: wpf

public class ProductRecord
    {
        private int _code;
        private string _name;
        private int _quantity;
        private string _size;
        private string _unit;
        private DateTime _dateOrdered;
        private string _manufacturer;

```
    public int Code { get { return _code; } set { _code = value; } }
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public int Quantity { get { return _quantity; } set { _quantity = value; } }
    public string Size { get { return _size; } set { _size = value; } }
    public string Unit { get { return _unit; } set { _unit = value; } }
    public DateTime DateOrdered { get { return _dateOrdered; } set { _dateOrdered = value; } }
    public string Manufacturer { get { return _manufacturer; } set { _manufacturer = value; } }


    public static List<ProductRecord> GetProductRecords()
    {
        List<ProductRecord> lstRecords = new List<ProductRecord>();
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ProductTable";
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ProductCore.ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            ProductRecord record = new ProductRecord();
            record.Code = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Code"]);
            record.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            record.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Quantity"]);
            record.Size = reader["Size"].ToString();
            record.Unit = reader["Unit"].ToString();
            record.DateOrdered = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOrdered"]);
            record.Manufacturer = reader["Manufacturer"].ToString();

            lstRecords.Add(record);

        } cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: this isn't a question. what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of lack of "return" keyword. You declared that your method will return object of type List, created instance of List in method body, and populated it in loop. But You didn't return that anywhere :) Simply add

```
return lstRecords;
```

at the end of method.